# Converting string to datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime, data-conversion

I have a simple three line script that converts a string to a datetime in Python.

```
from datetime import datetime

mydate='Feb-22-1732'

print(datetime.strptime(mydate,'%b-%dd-%Y'))
```

But when I run this code, I get an error saying:

```
ValueError: time data 'Feb-22-1732' does not match format '%b-%dd-%Y'
```

Can you please help me understand what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should do only ```datetime.strptime(mydate,'%b-%d-%Y')```

Comment: Thanks Manoj. You're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to repeat `d` two times - [`%d` handles two-digit days by definition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

> `%d` - Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.

```
print(datetime.strptime(mydate,'%b-%d-%Y'))
```